# Most used methods from external libraries

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-metrics

Is there any way to know the most used methods from **external libraries** within a **C#** project / solution? Right now, i'm using Visual Studio 2008 (but ansers for newer versions are ok).

Just need a simple listing like:

```
Namespace    Class     Method      Times used
---------------------------------------------
Namespace1   Class1    MethodA     10
Namespace1   Class2    MethodA     9
Namespace2   Class2    MethodB     7
```

Maybe there is no easy way, ideas for doing it programmatically are welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Then again this is something that might be covered inside Visual Studio so it's not necessarily asking for a tool. Help with IDE's is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

The commercial application [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can do that (and much more of course).

Comment: I've been trying NDepend. Shows a 'Third-Party Usage' chart with the global count of third party methods, types, assemblies and namespaces.  Can I see, somewhere else, more detailed statistics? Like in my example. Thanks.